# Need help using vertical align, issues with excess spacing on top of div

Tags: html, css, html-lists, vertical-alignment

http://le1dev.co.uk/artamura/2/order-prints/

I've managed to get my images to vertically align to the bottom, but now theres a lot of excess space at the top which is pushing the entire list down. Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Answer (score 0):

Just reduce the `line-height on .prod-div-2` and space will be decrease